# Christmas and New Year bounties, more 1 or 2 days for grace period?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, time

Christmas and New Year are short periods (1 or 2 days) of generalized reduction of flow in Stackoverflow. There are a rule for add more 1 or 2 days for grace period? Can we (users) require this rule here?

Comment: Meh. Unnecessary complication IMO. Just don't start a bounty when you're not sure you can award it in time

Comment: Any user can ask for any new feature (not rule) but not all requests are handled..

Comment: Obviously we're not very graceful people.

Comment: It's a bad idea but it doesn't deserve downvotes IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please no.

The week period for promotion means that anyone that is thinking of offering a bounty can calculate if they want to postpone asking it since they'll be out having fun when the bounty ends at [Diwali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwali) or [Sturgis Bike Week](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YqOjIm1rNQ) or any of the counting system rollover events (a.k.a new year's day) that people love to celebrate around the globe.

One of the nice things about Stack Exchange is that it is worldwide, very inclusive and tries to be open to everyone's time of communication in an equal manner. If anyone wants to avoid a time to issue a bounty, then they have that control today. Why code in some extra cases and have to worry about which dates to include as exceptions when there isn't a problem in the first place.