# Could the bounty system be more fair when bounty owners are "forgetful"?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, expired-bounty

Nowadays, bounties are often set on very specific, complex questions that are subject to require more work from those who will provide answers, and which would probably be of lesser interest to other SO users.

In this regard, bounties play two roles:

- For the person's posting the question and offering the bounty, it helps grab more visibility on their question, since it will be promoted to a distinct list of questions.
- For persons answering the question, it provides an incentive in putting more efforts on that question, rather that on some other that might be easier to answer.

Note that the second role is *required* for the bounty system to be coherent for that type of question. It is in some way a *promise* made by the bounty offerer that they will reward a good quality answer. Otherwise, there would be little interest from the answerer's point of view in putting *significantly more effort* in answering a question *that would help only one person*.

Unfortunately, once the bounty has been set up, there is absolutely no incentive for the bouncy offerer to react in a timely manner in regard with that bounty. From their point of view, they gained the extra visibility they wanted, and they will benefit from an answer, no matter if it comes before of after the bounty's expiration. Unfortunately, that means that very good answers, posted well in time, may get accepted a few hours or or a few days after the bounty has expired.

It has been said [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160151/237776) "Just don't start a bounty when you're not sure you can award it in time", and I also think so, but this claim is taken from the bounty offerer's perspective. Now, as an answerer, I have no way to know that the bounty offerer will show respect to those who will take time to do research and answer his question.

Could there be some work done in order to make it more fair for users that have contributed answers on bountied questions when the bounty offerer doesn't honor is duty to review and accept answers before the end of the bounty's grace period?

Here are some ideas:

- Make it possible for the bounty offerer to award the bounty some time after the expiration of the grace period if the bounty was not automatically awarded.
- Add a "request for bounty moderation" flag so that a moderator can review the timeline and determine if a deserved bounty was lost because of a fault from the bounty offerer's part.
- Grant some badge to those who have contributed answers to bountied questions, which got accepted after the expiration of the bounty.
- Penalize bounty offerers that do not "review" submitted answers before the expiration of the grace period.

Would that make sense?

Comment: I'd rather bounties just not exist

Comment: I agree. But it does exist, so I'd rather it to be fair.

Comment: in a sense i can understand what you're asking for... but... you kinda already know why it is the way it is. we don't force users to award a bounty, but want them to have some... pressure, or immediacy, to award it rather than just allowing them to reward it whenever so that they can't take advantage of answerers by holding the bounty until they get what they want.

Comment: Indeed, I understand. I'm also aware that a) the current bounty system is pretty stable overall, b) simply "changing the rules" is unlikely to end up in a better situation, c) adding complexity to the StackExchange's engine is something that should not be taken lightly, d) it is not in the community's interest to add too much more work on moderators' shoulders...

Answer (score 4):

There's already a system for this [in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount

Yes, that's only half the amount, but it's still an award. Also, the question being featured draws more attention to the question *and* the answers, so you'll get (on average) more upvotes than you would otherwise get if there wasn't a bounty.

Sometimes you put a lot of effort in a near-perfect answer of which you're sure it's helpful to the question author. They might even comment to indicate so, but still don't accept the answer. (This might even happen more often than the situation you describe.) We don't 'force' users to accept answers, and this is similar.

Comment: Yes I know about automatic bounty awarding rules. What I am saying is that they sometime fail _specifically because of the 24 hours deadline_. For example, in a recent case, the OP accepted my answer less than 2 hours after the bounty expiration, though I had posted it two days earlier. To be precise, in that case, I got no bounty at all, because the post attracted little attention, and is likely not to attract more attention in the future, since the question was very specific to that user.

Comment: And yes, I'm very well aware that we don't force users to accept answers. That's fine. Really. But then again, the current bounty rules create an awkward situation, where the OP do accept an answer, but not within the allowed time frame. So, by offering a bounty, the OP is basically saying "my question is more important than others", "rush for it" and "you will be rewarded", but then, some don't care accepting an answer in time for the bounty to be awarded.

Comment: The problem is that even if the OP thinks that he should have awarded the bounty to someone, he no longer can. OP can accept a solution years after an answer has been published, but can't wait… lets say "on next business day"… to award a bounty.

Comment: Well the problem is that you think you are entitled to the bounty, while it's at the bounty posters grace to decide whom to award to @jwatkins. I sometimes post a bounty and deliberately don't award it.

Comment: "it's at the bounty posters grace to decide whom to award to" Perfectly true. "I sometimes post a bounty and deliberately don't award it." Also true. I don't disagree with either of these points. What I am saying is that the system impose a very short timeout for the bounty offerer to decide if we wants to award the bounty, though he has no incentive to respect that deadline, and no way to do it later.